# emojicon is not bound

Tags: android, xml

I am implementing the emojicon library in my android project, but when I try to this error comes out:

Namespace emojicon is not bound

Here's the xml I am using:

```
    <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEmojicon"
    android:text="I \ue32d emojicon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
    android:id="@+id/editEmojicon"
    android:text="I \ue32d emojicon"
    emojicon:emojiconSize="28sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/emojicons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    class="com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconsFragment"/>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this namespace to your layout:

```
xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Reference: Emojicon sample code given [here](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/blob/master/example/res/layout/activity_main.xml)

Comment: what does actually `xmlns:emojicon` refer to? I mean is this referring to something custom or from android..?

Comment: @eRaisedToX: `xmlns:` is namespace declaration in XML. More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)